# Pusher.com - get notified server side when someone connects/disconnects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pusher

Using presence channels in Pusher (http://pusher.com), how can I get notified server side when someone connects or disconnects from a presence channel? Is it even possible? My server is running PHP.

I found a similar question on Pusher's support. Phil Leggetter who answerd said that there are two possible workarounds. But they aren't presented. Here is that question:
https://pusher.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/65-how-to-see-that-a-user-is-still-alive-on-a-private-channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that support issue, Pusher have introduced [presence WebHooks](http://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#presence/lang=php) that allow you to listen to presence events (`member_added` and `member_removed`).

This should provide you with exactly the information you are looking for.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with $app_secret = getenv('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'); Should I define PUSHER_APP_SECRET somewhere?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php Or, you can replace that line and bring in the secret value from a constant. Or, you could hard-code in your secret as long as you know that nobody else will see the code.